# Can EasyPHP take command line arguments?

Tags: php, command-line, easyphp

I want to write a PHP program that takes an argument from the command line but am not sure how it's done. I use EasyPHP for development, do I need something different?

In the [user notes](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) it says you can

```
$ php -f somefile.php a=1 b[]=2 b[]=3
```

But when I try something like this (even `php -i`) it says php is not a recognized program. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with easyphp, but it sounds like you need to find php.exe (probably in the folder where you installed easyphp) and add it to your Path settings in windows.